# Why does vim add ^J to the end of my macros?

Tags: vimrc, external-command, macro

I wrote short macro that helps me grep for the word under the cursor. Here it is in my .vimrc:

```
let @a=":! git grep ^R^W^M"
```

However, when I open vim and run `:reg a`, I see the following:

```
"a   :! git grep ^R^W^M^J
```

You can see an ^J has been added to the macro.

If I remove the ^M in my script, then the ^J disappears also.

It seems the ^J acts similar to ^M. So, it's like I have two ^M. This isn't what I want, because I can't see the result of my command. The window just flashes before I can read it.

I have gotten my script to work by pasting and then copying it. The problem only arises when I try to load it using my .vimrc.

Answer (score 1):

For whatever weird reason, it works fine if you replace the `^M^J` with `^J`:

```
:let @a=":! git grep \<c-r>\<c-w>\<c-j>"
:reg a
"a   :! git grep ^R^W^J
```

And `@a` works as expected.

(I'm using [the `\<...>` notation](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#expr-string) since it is easier to copy paste.)

---

Technically, `^M` is the carriage return and `^J` is the newline. I'm not sure how the difference matters in this case.

Comment: I'll give that a shot, but how do I enter ^J? I know how to enter ^M, but not ^J.

Comment: Oh, I understand. I'll use \<...>, then.

Comment: @user2445507 how do you enter C-M?

Comment: ^M is entered by pressing <ctrl+v> and then <ctrl+m>. <ctrl+v> goes into some special mode that lets you write special characters that begin with ^.

Comment: @user2445507 and that didn't work for ^J?

Comment: No, it prints ^@ for some reason